# How to sync NSUserDefaults with RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, nsuserdefaults

I find lots of open source projects target on syncing NSUserDefaults data with iCloud, but I just want to sync it to my own server, how to do it with RestKit? some solutions:

1. Create a normal core data model Settings:NSManagedObject, and get/patch as normal.

   - Pros, no need NSUserDefaults, and I can communicate with the server through RestKit.
   - Cons, just looks weird, the model `Settings` will only have one instance.
2. Create a normal NSObject Settings:NSObject, map the json from the server to this object and then pass all information to NSUserDefaults, and get/patch through `Settings`

   - Pros, I'm do syncing NSUserDefaults with RestKit.
   - Cons, need to implement two map, one is from json to `Settings`, one is from `Settings` to NSUserDefaults. And too complicate.

Comment: What have you considered and tried ?

Comment: thanks again @Wain, just updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I usually go with your option 2, but either will work.

An idea for you to toy with:

Create your settings object as a proxy. It implements the invocation / selector methods of a proxy so it can forward all of the setter and getter methods it's passed on, in this case to user defaults. It uses the selector it's passed to create the user defaults key to store or retrieve the data from.

Now, any config you setup in your mapping will automatically go to user defaults with a corresponding key.

It's not an obvious solution, i.e. you can't see what it's doing easily by reading the code, but it's a very low lines of code solution.

Comment: Get it, thanks I'll try option 2 and let you know the result later.